# how to set an absolute position to a view (or div class)?

Tags: views, navigation, theming

I have 2 views that displays ads on both sidebars of the page. on top of one of them, is another view that displays articles. the view that displays articles can be a height of anywhere between 20px, and 200px, depending on how many articles there are at the time. I need the ads underneath it to be aligned with the ads on the other sidebar. If I use something like margin-top, it will only work if there are the same amount of articles throughout the life of the site. I was hoping to do something like anchor the view to the bottom, or to set a specific position to put the view.

Comment: This is a CSS question, not a Drupal question

Comment: which StackExchange site do I ask css questions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

If you have the div's parent element set to position: relative, you can then set the ad div to be position: relative and give it and offset from the bottom. eg. bottom: 20px;
You will need to be careful that your article list div doesn't expand over the space where your ads are as they will overlap.
Post a link if you need more help.
Hope this helps.